# How to turn off auto code folding in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, editor, phpstorm

Every time when I try to edit a folding line (or move this line to a new location) — all lines unfold. If possible, how can I turn off this function?

Here is an example of my problem:
[Code Folding in phpStorm (bug or features?)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJbJMkxg1H4)

Comment: It's a bug -- I believe there are tickets about such behaviour -- check their Issue Tracker ([PHP](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)  and [JS/HTML/CSS](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB))

Comment: Every time I look at PhpStorm and try to type something, I go back to Notepad++.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**To configure auto-folding behavior in the editor**

1. Open the Settings dialog box.
2. Under Editor > General, click Code Folding. Code Folding page is displayed.
3. In the 'Fold by default' list, select the check boxes to the left of the code constructs you want to be displayed collapsed.
4. Apply changes.

Reference: [Code Folding Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-folding-settings.html#)